# Long title flexbox/ellipsis in React Native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am trying to have a title fit with an ellipsis if it's too long for the device width, so the **priorities in red** below can always show at all times:

[image]

The above is what it should look like.
It works very well with a short title, but looks like this now:

[image]

I set up a working example here: https://rnplay.org/apps/heKkoQ

Try a short title, you'll see how it looks correct, but with the long title, it does not fit the priority.

Can someone jump in with a working solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add `flex: 1` to header container style and `flexShrink: 1` to title style. Also use `ellipsizeMode='tail'` and  `numberOfLines={1}` props for title.

Comment: Thank for jumping in! This works perfectly for the long title, but the issue is if you make the title short, you'll see there is a huge white space between the title and the separator/time. Ideally, it should work for both titles short/long.

Comment: Use `flexShrink` instead `flex` for title then.